# How is the union of $[0, 1 -2^{-n})$ (over all positive integers n) a cover of $[0, 1]$ in the lower limit topology of R?

Tags: general-topology

How is the union of $[0, 1 -2^{-n})$ (over all positive integers $n$ ) a cover of $[0, 1]$ in the lower limit topology of $\Bbb R $

Isn't this union equal to $[0, 1)$?

Also, how does it not have an finite subcover? Again, isn't this union equal to $[0, 1)$?

(This comes from a set of solutions to an old MGRE.)

If the singleton set $\{1\}$ is required in the union to make it a cover, can someone please still explain why not have the union of $[0, 1)$ with $\{1\}$ as a finite cover?

Update: Said MGRE solution was barely understandable.  But, I understand now what it was trying to say, which was that since there exists a (aforementioned) cover (union the intersection that gives the singleton set) for which a finite subcover does not exist, then $[0,1]$ is not compact.

Comment: You need to include an additional set containing $1$. Then it's an open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: Does it say somewhere that that union is a cover of that interval? Where?

Comment: @MattSamuel That was what I thought.  I have a set of solutions to a MGRE exam that is apparently flawed.  And you mean a singleton set, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah, in a set of solutions to an old MGRE exam .

Comment: In this topology, a singleton set containing $1$ would indeed be open, so that would work, but really any basic open set not containing the whole interval would do the trick.

Comment: @MattSamuel Why not containing the whole set?

Comment: Well then the set would just be $[0,1]$ and there would be a finite subcover.

Comment: @MattSamuel why can that not by a finite subcover?

Comment: There can be, but I thought the goal was not to have one.

Comment: The union of the sets in a cover need not be an element of the cover. In particular $[0,1)$ is not an element of the cover.

Comment: @MattSamuel I get that, but if $[0,1)$ union {1} (or $[1,r)$ for some $r>1$) is a finite subcover, then that makes [0,1] compact.  But, it isn't, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the union is [0,1).
To additionally cover [0,1], add any open set containing 1.
[1,2), for example. Thus you have an open cover with no finite
subcover showing [0,1] is not compact.  Continue this exercise
to conclude the lower limit topology is not locally compact.

Comment: Does irreducible mean that it has no finite subcover?

Comment: It means cannot be made smaller.  See edit.